# I'm Trying to create a flask app that download a file from internet on heroku. But i don't know where file is getting stored

Tags: python, heroku, flask, web-applications

Here is the code. It works on localhost and download files where the app.py is kept.

```
import requests
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return '<h1>Hello World!</h1>'

@app.route('/download')
def download():
    download_url = "https://www.python.org/static/community_logos/python-logo-master-v3-TM.png"
    r = requests.get(download_url)
    with open("python_logo.png",'wb') as f: 
        f.write(r.content)
    return "<h2>Download Complete<h2>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

I don't want to use S3 to upload files because the file size will be 2-3 MB and I dont want to spend on S3.

Comment: Please give more context about what you try to do, what you tried that isn't working and what you would need.

Comment: @jjacobi I'm trying to make an app on which user can upload files and get google drive link.

Comment: You can maybe use the Google drive API see the following link: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python

Comment: @jjacobi i know about Gdrive api but the main problem is i don't know where the downloaded files are getting stored on heroku. If I'm trying this code on local host the image gets downloaded in the same folder where the others files are stored but when i try to run this code on heroku i'm not able to find that image file.

Comment: I'm not sure you have local storage access on Heroku cloud functions. You can therefore store the file in memory with `BytesIO` (`from io import BytesIO`) and upload it after to the Google cloud storage API.

Comment: @jjacobi can you please explain more about that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to spend anything on S3 if your uploads are of 2-3 MB size. AWS S3 provides, for free, 5 GB of standard storage with  which is secure, durable, and scalable object storage infrastructure. You can make 20,000 Get Requests and 2,000 Put Requests. It is not recommended to store the uploaded objects on the web server's disk. AWS provides reasonably good storage space for free tier. If you going to exceed these limits you will anyway have to consider moving beyond free cloud storage tier.